# Eclipse RCP: How to properly create a toolbar with global actions using the Command framework?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I my RCP application there is a view with a TreeViewer inside. Using the Command framework, I’m trying to populate its toolbar with items that would perform common actions on the tree elements, such as “delete", “properties" etc.

I would like the icons to be enabled/disabled according to the TreeViewer’s selection state, but they should always be visible.

Here is what I came up with so far (I’m showing only the delete command, the others are very similar):

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
    <handler commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete" class="my.custom.DeleteHandler">
        <activeWhen>
            <with variable="activePartId">
                <equals value="my.custom.ViewPart" />
            </with>
        </activeWhen>
        <enabledWhen>
            <count value="(0-" />
        </enabledWhen>
    </handler>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution locationURI="toolbar:my.custom.ViewPart">        
        <command commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete" label="Delete" />
    </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

Everything works fine as long as the active part is my tree view. But when the focus goes, say, to an editor, the buttons get activated. I suppose this happens because my custom handlers are deactivated in favor of the default workbench handlers.

How can I keep the "delete", "properties" items visible but disabled, when the active part is not my view part?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `<activeWhen>` instead put all your conditions in the `<enabledWhen>`:

```xml
<enabledWhen>
  <and>
     <count value="(0-" />
     <with variable="activePartId">
        <equals value="my.custom.ViewPart" />
     </with>
   </and>
</enabledWhen>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that, but it did not solve the problem. The toolbar items get enabled as soon as the focus goes outside the view part.